# RuntimeException MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase

On HDP cluster, I am trying create and integrate Hive tables with existing Hbase tables. It creates the hive table. But when I am try to query the hive table it throws the following exception *especially when the number of columns exceeds 200*.

I checked the # of columns in both hbase & hive is same. Not getting proper solution to debug it.

```
hive> select * from hbase_hive.lead;

FAILED: RuntimeException MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseSerDe: 
columns has 273 elements while hbase.columns.mapping has 204 elements (counting the key if implicit))
```

Is there any column limitation in this case?

Please suggest me solution on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This has fixed the issue.](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/33311/number-column-limitations-in-hive-over-hbase-table.html)

https://hortonworks.my.salesforce.com/kA2E0000000LZQ5?srPos=0&srKp=ka2⟨=en_US

#### ROOT CAUSE:

A character limitation for PARAM_VALUE field in SERDE_PARAMS table in hive metastore for 4000 character is the root cause of this issue. This limitation prevents Hive from creating a table with high column numbers, eventually causing desc  or select * from  to fail with error above.

#### WORKAROUND: This issue can be worked around by doing the following in hive metastore

```
-- log into Hive Metastore DB -- >alter table SERDE_PARAMS MODIFY PARAM_VALUE VARCHAR(400000000);
```

Comment: Hi, you could also change the type to text - this would be highly beneficial for file types like json where you may have large number of columns.